# how to create a function prototype namespace

Tags: c++

I'm new to cpp and was just wondering, how do I add a function prototype above the main loop for a namespace, sorry if that's not the right term for what I'm talking about. But basically I want to define or declare the namespace as you would a function above the main loop so that it loads in to memory and can be called. I'm aware it's probably not normal to have a namespace on your main cpp so normally you could just include the header file and that would do it but I'm just messing around and am curious.

so basically this

```
void foo(); // declaring so that the function is loaded in to memory to be used

int main(){

    void foo(); 
}

void foo(){  
    do something;
}
```

but with namespace so instead of foo(); it would be

```
namespace fly {

void helicopter() {
    do something;
}
```

}

Comment: what you want to achieve here?

Comment: *"declare the namespace as you would a function above the main loop so that it loads in to memory and can be called"* You can't call a namespace. I don't understand the question. Can you demonstrate what you want to get with more code?

Comment: I just want to be able to call a function using for example fly::helicopter(); but as it's below the piece of code I want to call it it's not in memory yet so I cant. I mean I could just put it above that code but I'd like to know how you would do it,

Comment: Declarations do not load anything into memory. They're just notes to the compiler so that it can understand and process your code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I tried just adding namespace fly; above the main loop and it didn't work

Comment: @moderategamer loading into memory is something different. What you're having trouble with is [_scope_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to declare my function so I can call it even though it is below the function that's calling it. I'd appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to do that thanks

Comment: A terminology note: `int main()` is the main *function* not the main loop. A main loop is something else, typical for graphical programs, not necessarily directly in the main function.

Comment: Yes sorry I misspoke @JaMiT

Comment: @moderategamer Please understand I meant that as a tip for the future. If you use terminology correctly, you might get fewer downvotes. Some people might have read this question, saw things that didn't make sense, then voted down without taking time to try to figure out what you meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namespaces aren't things.  They don't exist in memory, you can't call them.  Namespaces exist only to qualify the names of other things.  As such, you can open and close a namespace as many times as you like, but you can't declare one.  That wouldn't do anything.

If you want to separate the declaration and definition of a *function* within a namespace, that's fine.  Either re-open the namespace for the definition:

```
namespace fly {
    void helicopter();
}

int main() {
    fly::helicopter();
}

namespace fly {
    void helicopter() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or fully-qualify the function's name when you define it:

```
namespace fly {
    void helicopter();
}

int main() {
    fly::helicopter();
}

void fly::helicopter() {
    // ...
}
```